# html5 web app for android and other devices : resizable images

Tags: android, css, html, image

i am developing android app using html5+ crosswalk project for android 
my main concern are images :
 as i will be using same app for table and other mobile devices

is there some thing like resizable images ??

i call images

is there something that fro tablet we can call [image]
for mobile small width [image]

or some concept of resizable images

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of **picturefill** which says for different screen sizes you can load different images and it basically decides using the media queries specified.
For detail you can see [here](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/)